# Python recursion returning old value

Tags: python, recursion, return

I'm trying to make a simple control in Python 2 to make sure that the user's input is smaller than a given constant. If this is not the case it should ask again for another integer until it is smaller.

```
limit_store = 12

def input_store():
    sel_store = int(raw_input("Which store do you want? "))
    if sel_store > limit_store:
        print "Store number %i is not valid" % sel_store
        input_store()  
    return sel_store

store = input_store()
```

This worked the first time I wrote it in an Ipython notebook. Now if the first input is 9, it returns 9 as expected. If the input is 999, which is larger than 12, the if statement is runned and we get to select another integer. Selecting a correct input after a wrong one will return the old wrong input instead of the newer input.

Comment: You would need to `return input_store()`, the value of `sel_store` will be stored on the first call to the function so if you enter 100 different numbers you will always get the first unless you return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save the value after printing the "invalid" message.

```
if sel_store > limit_store:
    print "Store number %i is not valid" % sel_store
    sel_store = input_store() # save value here
```

`return`ing the number instead of saving it would also work - as long as the number goes somewhere useful instead of being thrown away. Python [doesn't have TCO](http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2009/04/tail-recursion-elimination.html), so the performance benefit is minimal. The difference is in what you find preferable: that your function has a single `return` statement, or that it `return`s immediately instead of saving the variable first.

It would be simpler as a loop anyway:

```
def input_store():
    while True:
        sel_store = int(raw_input("Which store do you want? "))
        if sel_store <= limit_store: break
        print "Store number %i is not valid" % sel_store
    return sel_store
```

Comment: or just ```return input_store()```

Comment: So sorry. I forget to include that piece in the post. I'm editing now.

Comment: No - immediately after printing the "invalid" message, within the function.

Comment: I think it worked. I still not sure why my version doesn't work but I understand why your does. Thanks.

Comment: It's because you saved the initial attempt, but then the returned value of the recursive call wasn't saved, so in effect you had a line that was just a statement containing some number, which the interpreter immediately threw away.

Comment: So if python had TCO the code might run ok? It is strange that I have to define the variable twice.

Comment: No, TCO would make a tail-recursive function (a recursive function where the recursive call is the last thing in the function) faster/neater for the compiler. Python doesn't do that because TCO eliminates the stack and Guido wanted the stack available for debugging. It's perfectly fine to assign to a variable twice if the first assignment fails an error check.